# Codeigniter Multiple image upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, file, image-uploading

I am trying to upload multiple images using code-igniter

Following is the form code I am using

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('garage/quote');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile[]"   />
<input type="file" name="userfile[]"   />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

and then i use following code to upload

```
$this->load->library('upload');

            $files = $_FILES;
            $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
            for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
            {           
                $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

                $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
                if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
                     $this->db->insert('attachment', array(
                        'type'      =>   'quotation',
                        'typeid'    =>   $lastid, 
                        'path'      =>   $_FILES['userfile']['name'],
                     ));  
                }
                else {
                    print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
                }
            }
```

Now problem is that it uploads only one image instead of two.

I tried following code as well

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile[]')){
```

but it didn't work  .

Please help me how can I upload multiple images?

Comment: show the `set_upload_options()` function.

Comment: Mostly it will be the problem from `set_upload_options()` because rest of your code works fine for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251111/multiple-file-upload-results-in-foreach-error/45251554#45251554